# Backoffice : Server error occurred while loading tabs

Tags: tabs, loading, prestashop, server-error

First of all I am working with Prestashop 1.6.0.11.

Recently, I have a warning pop-up that appears in my back office when I try to make a change to one of my products.

'A server error occurred while loading tabs: all tabs could not be loaded.

Please try again by refreshing the page.
If you still experience the problem, please check your server logs or contact your provider for more information. '

I currently have a total of 9 categories and subcategories.
I have been researching on Prestashop forum and google but I have not found anything of a supporting on the subject ...

The first idea that I came to mind was a server level performance issue but I already have a professional hosting so I do not think it came from there and especially I have never had this problem before on many shops I realized.

Comment: It's a generic errors, meaning that generating the tab content resulted in error and no valid ajax response wasr eturned. You must check your PHP error log to see what happened while it was being generated.

Answer (score 1):

I simply disable the module "Blog for PrestaShop - Related Posts" and it works !!

Answer (score 0):

increased the max_execution_time and memory_limit for your domain